create a load balancer with Cloud Run, GCP. do i need external ip address? and load balancer ip, not certed
my goal is to do SSL pinning (mobile apps), with my cloud run backend
Plan A:
Creating a domain mapping for cloud run service, is there a no way to get the SSL cert? looks like its not possible.
Plan B:
Setup load balancer in front of cloud run
Followed instructions on https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https-serverless
Setup

"Create the load balancer" section > Frontend > create cert > Google managed cert. domain: "api.(mydomain).com"
"Connect your domain to your load balancer" section. I added this to my DNS: "record=A" "name=api" and "data=(load balancer ip address)"
testing load balancer. https://api.(mydomain).com -> load balancer address. works fine. but the load balancer ip address has no cert?

Questions with load balancer:

"reserved an external IP address" section. I reserved an external IP address. but what do i do with this? this is line 1 of image. looks like "create a load balancer" instructions already created an IP, see line 2 of image.

load balancer ip has no cert. but via https://api.(mydomain).com does. is that right?

other links i read
Configuring Cloud Run services and GCS Buckets with a load balancer

For "Plan A", you can use e.g. openssl (or a language-specific tool) to interrogate the server for its certificates (openssl s_client -connect ${NAME}:443 --showcerts). Google recommends against pinning for Android apps.
